# when running "yarn ios" I keep getting "The following build commands failed: Ld...."

Tags: react-native, build, xcode13

I've been stuck on this one on two projects now! (silly me didn't write down how I solved this issue the first time around ‍♂️.) I have a react native project and running yarn ios brings me this error

`Ld /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-hash/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/appname.app/appname normal (in target 'appname' from project 'appname')`

I've tried in random orders (if I need to be doing these in specific orders please let me know)

- deleting DerivedData/appnamefolder
- cleaning xcode build folder
- deleting and re-installing pods
- deleting, cleaning yarn cache, and reinstalling node-modules via yarn.

I'm running out of ideas and all articles I've read seem to only point to the above solutions which are not working for me.

Environment

- Mac(Intel)Monterey 12.0.1
- React Native 0.64.2
- NPM@8.3.0 (global)
- xCode 13.1

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: Hi there, yeah I was.

Comment: I basically deleted pods, pods.lock, node modules, yarn.lock, went to About This Mac->Storage->Developer and deleted the Project Build Data and Indexes, cleaned cache in Xcode just for good measure. cleaned cache with yarn/npm, cleaned pod cache. JIC. then in this order I.... installed node modules, re-installed pods, then it worked for me. ‍♂️

I've run into a couple more times with the PHP script and it usually has to do with the pods not being in sync with node modules, or if you add a new dependency, etc. make sure to pod install.

Comment: hi, i tried what is described in the post above am also facing this issue. did u try anything other then this?

Comment: could you write the commands and in steps which worked. Thanks

Comment: @BrettSaxon I am also facing the exact same issue. I also forgot how I resolved it earlier. Can you please break down your solution explanations into commands?

Comment: @MuhammadAqeel - this is the order from above here. 
I basically deleted pods, pods.lock, node modules, yarn.lock, went to About This Mac->Storage->Developer and deleted the Project Build Data and Indexes, cleaned cache in Xcode just for good measure. cleaned cache with yarn/npm, cleaned pod cache. JIC. then in this order I.... installed node modules, re-installed pods, then it worked for me. ‍♂️ I've run into a couple more times with the PHP script and it usually has to do with the pods not being in sync with node modules, or if you add a new dependency, etc.

Comment: Also there are new issues with XCode 14.3. if you're running RN < 0.69.9 you'll need to revert to Xcode 14.2. or upgrade your project. Issue here -> https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36739

Answer (score 0):

In my own case, I was getting this error

```bash
Ld /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-***/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppName.app/AppName normal (in target 'AppName' from project 'AppName')
(1 failure)(1 failure)
```

The steps mentioned by the author above worked for me

1. Delete your pods: cd `ios` and run `rm -rf pods && rm podfile.lock` and then `cd ../` (back to root folder)
2. delete your `yarn.lock` or `npm.lock` and `node_modules` folder: run `rm -rf node_modules && rm yarn.lock`
3. Delete `Project Build Data and Indexes` and `XCode cache`: go to system preferences and search for storage. Click on storage settings, Click on `Developer` and delete `Project Build Data and Indexes and XCode cache`

   [image]

4. Clear your caches

*clear pods cache*

```
    rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"
    rm -rf "`pwd`/Pods/"
    pod update
```

*clear npm/ yarn cache*

```
npm cache clean --force 
yarn cache clean
```

5. re-install all in the order - node_modules, and pods

- in your root folder run `yarn install` or `npm install`
- then cd `ios` and run `pod install`